# What are the Japanese names of the columns in a Kana chart? (Vowels, K, S, T...)

Tags: word-requests, kana, terminology

Here is a typical Kana chart presented in gojūon order:

[image]

In English, I refer to the first column in the chart as the 'vowels' and I refer to every other column in the chart with the first letter of each Kana in English (K, S, T...).

How would I refer to a particular column of this chart in spoken Japanese?

If for example, I was struggling to remember a word such as 'りんご' but I could only remember the consanant part from the final consonant + vowel pair (ri,n,g—), how could I say...

> "I think the last kana was a 'g—' kana..."

Comment: Possibly of interest: [How to refer to kana verbally](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41840/how-to-refer-to-kana-verbally)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The word you are looking for is 「行{ぎょう}」.

Therefore, the columns are named 「ア行」、「カ行」、「サ行」, etc.

> How could I say "I think the last kana was a 'g—' kana...'?

You could say:

> 「最後{さいご}の文字{もじ}は**ガ行のかな**だったと思{おも}う。」

In case someone is wondering what we call the horizontal rows of kana on that chart, they are called 「段{だん}」.  We say 「ア段」、「イ段」, etc.

Comment: I assumed they would use the first kana from the top but I assumed there might be an exception for the vowels. I will practice this phrase, thank you!